# Convert passwords created with PWDENCRYPT to HASHBYTES

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, hashbytes

We have been using `PWDENCRYPT` in our site to hash passwords - but want to change it to using `HASHBYTES`.

Is it possible to make this conversion automatic? I know that it is not possible to decrypt those strings - but what have I to consider to make this conversion?

Thanks in advance for an answer.

Comment: Why use either method? Any method would be weaker than [the built-in authentication providers used by all .NET/.NET Core stacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity). The built-in providers would salt the password and hash it for *at least* 1000 times using a strong hash algorithm. The cleartext password would never be sent to the database.

Comment: .NET's [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-5.0) provides a standards based, secure way of generating hashes from passwords through salting, repeated hashing and strong message hashing algorithms. If you want to use a stronger hashing algorithm, you can do so by passing the desired algorithm as a constructor parameter

Comment: The point of hashing is that no one can get access to the original password. That's why it's called one way encryption.

Comment: @Liam Thanks for answering. But if we change algorithm - will the users have to retype their passwords because of the oneway encryption? And because of the missing decrypt function of passwords?

Comment: Yes, like I said, hashed passwords are designed to be unrecoverable. It's designed that way so that if someone gets your data the passwords are unusable and it also prevents you (or anyone who has access to the data) to be able to see anyones passwords (as passwords get re-used). So there is no way to move from x hashed password to y. You'll have to come up with another solution

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to directly convert between the two, but if you can modify the application code, one solution could be to gradually phase out the use of `PWDENCRYPT`.

When a user attempts to log in, check if their hashed password is stored with `PWDENCRYPT` or `HASHBYTES`. If the hash is stored with `HASHBYTES`, validate the entered password and log the user in. If the hash is stored with `PWDENCRYPT` (and validated) then promt the user to chose a new password before continuing. When the user has chosen a new password, hash it using `HASHBYTES`, and blank out the `PWDENCRYPT` hash.

After some time, most password-hashes will have been migrated to using `HASHBYTES` and you can disable the use of `PWDENCRYPT`. If a user who has not yet migrated attempts to log in, they will need to go through the "reset password" process (which of course should use `HASHBYTES`).

**DISCLAIMER**; if you can modify the application code, I ***strongly*** suggest that you instead use some of the built-in mechanisms for hashing and validating passwords, such as Microsofts own [PasswordHasher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0).